# Was a droid uploading into the Millennium Falcon Navi-Computer inspired by the old Han Solo novels?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, solo-a-star-wars-story

In *Solo: A Star Wars Story* we see

> L3-37 get uploaded into the Millennium Falcon Navi-Computer.

Now, I understand that this links to what C-3P0 says in the *Empire Strikes Back*:

> "Sir, I don't know where your ship learned to communicate, but it has the most peculiar dialect."

But I also remember in the original Solo books, *Han Solo at Stars End*, *Han Solo's Revenge* and *Han Solo and the Lost Legacy*, that Han refuses to get the Falcon Navi-computer wiped or rewritten and even dislikes Blue Max interfacing with it. Is this also an inspiration for this scene?

I realise that the Legends series is not canon but Disney and the writers of the Disney *Star Wars* universe have shown a willingness to lift ideas from the Legends series.

Comment: _"That was something that came out of a lot of conversations with Larry, Phil, Chris and I about how to make it, how to retcon a little bit and say, how could she not only be a great character that we wanted, but a part of the story we didn't realise was there?

"And giving the Falcon a personality that is fused with this amazing character played by Phoebe I think does actually enrich the other movies in a way that I'm excited about."_ - Solo Writer Jonathan Kasdan.

Comment: Your title was too ambiguous. Most people who see the phrase "old Solo novels" will think of Napoleon Solo, the Man from U.N.C.L.E.

Comment: @user14111 Actually the Han Solo adventures are exactly the books I was thinking of from the title.

Answer (score 1):

**It is possible, though not likely.**

There are differences too. Blue Max was a slicer. L3-37 was a pilot. More importantly, Blue Max and Bollux survived their adventures with Solo.

There was also a droid that worked with Lando in Legends, temporarily. The only difference-a minor one- was it was an extra-galactic droid. This droid was called Vuffi Raa, and it was Lando's navigator. Vuffi Raa was the most likely inspiration for L3-37, though it returned home instead of being destroyed.

Comment: I don't think he's asking "was one of these characters the inspiration for L3-37", but rather is "Han refuses to get the Falcon Navi-computer wiped or re written and even dislikes Blue Max interfacing with it" the inspiration for having L3-37 get uploaded to the computer.